# Howto create a observer like communication between actors with Akka

Tags: akka, observer-pattern

In classical programming, I use the obeserver pattern in case I want to notify observers about changes.

What is the equivalent pattern in Akka?

Use case:

- An actor (PropertyServiceActor) is reading and caching properties form the DB
- Different actors can register to the PropertyServiceActor
- If a property changes, the PropertyServiceActor notifies the registered actors about the change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [BroadcastGroup](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.1/index.html#akka.routing.BroadcastGroup)

```
//Create group
val paths = List("/user/workers/w1", "/user/workers/w2", "/user/workers/w3")
val observers: ActorRef =  context.actorOf(BroadcastGroup(paths).props(), "observers")
```

To notify all observers just send message to `observers` ActorRef. Also you can add and remove observers by sending `akka.routing.AddRoutee` and `akka.routing.RemoveRoutee`.

You can find more [routing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html) docs.